# Unable to delete Solr index for a file

Tags: solr, solr4

I am issuing following query in a web browser to delete an index from Solr. The id of the indexed file which can be seen while querying Solr is C:\\Files\\T111\\testfile.rtf
and the query is:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test_core/update?stream.body=<delete><id>C:\\abc\\T111\\testfile.rtf</id></delete>&commit=true
```

Once the request is completed I am getting the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
    <int name="QTime">335</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

I believe the request is successful but I am still seeing the index in the Solr once I do a query.

Why am I getting an unexpected result? Could you please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the id have double \\ s? Or just one? My guess is that the number of \'s is off..

Answer (score 0):

Use missed `<query>` tag. you should specify like `<query>field-name:value</query>`

Try this. Replace `id` value accordingly

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test_core/update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:298253</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Comment: I got exceptions as <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
<str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.parser.ParseException</str>

Comment: Check with id value you passed. need to escape if any special character